# IFrame is squished when centered

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So I'm currently having the problem that i can't center a IFrame vertically. When i try to do it via "align-items: center" it gets squished like this:

[image]

The following is the source code snippet:

```
import "./Borderless-IFrame.css"

export const Stream = () =\>
\<div style={{
              display: "flex",
              height: '100%',
              alignItems: "center"
}}\>
\<iframe style={{width: '100%', height: "auto"}}
         src="http://localhost/" title='stream'\>\</iframe\>
\</div\>
```

So why does the window get squished like that? Has it something to do with being an IFrame? And if so, how do i properly center it? If i remove the align-items everything works fine, just the Iframe is stuck to the top.

Note that this project is not in the browser, it uses electron(chromium) and a stylesheet to have multiple tabs in one window. Maybe these are the problem, but I don't think so.

P.S.:
Also i noticed that the IFrame takes up the whole available space while the html contained inside the IFrame is smaller, when not centered. Why is that so?

I tried alternatives, suggest by others online to center the IFrame, nothing worked so far and i believe that this approach is the right one, except for the bug.

Comment: Afaik, CSS handles replaced elements specifically in some cases including `auto` values. It seems that iframe is squished to its default height around 150px. Try to apply CSS `aspect-ratio` property on it: `aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;` for example

Comment: That works, thank you, but i still have some weird padding below the IFrame do you maybe have a clue why?

Comment: Aren't there any borders? Try setting `border: 0`